# React+Express+MongoDB - correct POST request

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, post

I would like to know what is a good way to make POST request.

I created view with google map and marker with coordinates using react-google-maps. I store markers in react component using array of objects like this:

MapComponent.js

```
const markers = this.props.markers.map((pos,i) => {
    const marker={
      position:{
        lat:pos.location.lat,
        lng:pos.location.lng
      }
    }
    return <Marker key={i} {...marker}/>
  })
```

I am getting info about markers from AppComponent which is returning this:

```
<div className='container' style={{height:600}}>
        <Map center={location} markers={markers}/>
      </div>
```

where markers are :

```
const markers=[
    {
      location:{
        lat: 40.7575285,
        lng: -73.9884469
      }
    }
  ]
```

Now I would like to get markers' coordinates via POST request. Client will send POST with JSON data with his/her current location.Then I would like to store each coordinate in MongoDB refresh page and display marker with current location which I got from JSON. What is the best way to do that? Should I use POST only using Express?

Comment: There is no need in involving something bigger that POST request, and simple DB queries, so your approach seems to be correct

Comment: yeah but how can i properly make POST? I should use redux? How can I pass info from backend to frontend

Comment: You can perform POST operations using simple forms, and/or jquery, backend to frontend via res.json

Comment: so I don't need redux?